# Delete every non utf-8 symbols from string

Tags: python, mongodb, encode

I have a big amount of files and parser. What I Have to do is strip all non utf-8 symbols and put data in mongodb. 
Currently I have code like this.

```
with open(fname, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        line = line.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

somehow I still get an error

```
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: 
1/b62010montecassianomcir\xe2\x86\x90ta0\xe2\x86\x90008923304320733/290066010401040101506055soccorin
```

I don't get it. Is there some simple way to do it?

**UPD**: seems like Python and Mongo don't agree about definition of Utf-8 Valid string.

Comment: In my head algrithm of parsing is not very important end point is in first few lines. Maybe I'm mistaken

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try below code line instead of last two lines. Hope it helps:

```
line=line.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: I have some invisible chars which are appearing only after insertion. any fix for this?

Comment: @user168983 can you give an example

Comment: this `line.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8")` produce this error _AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'_, i work with python3

Comment: @ChediBechikh Here is how you do it in python3 `bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8','ignore')`

Comment: this does not change anything, the error exist when printing so i write this code  `print(ligne.rstrip().encode('utf-8','ignore')) ` but the problem with encode is , it add a b caracter like **b'press'**

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get lots of special chars:    `\00\00\00\00\00`

Comment: It looks like the only difference between the code in the question and the answer is that encode() no longer has ignore. Why would this make a difference? The default is strict which would raise an exception rather than skip the invalid utf8?

Answer (score 38):

For python 3, as mentioned in a comment in this thread, you can do:

```
line = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

The 'ignore' parameter prevents an error from being raised if any characters are unable to be decoded.

If your line is already a bytes object (e.g. `b'my string'`) then you just need to decode it with `decode('utf-8', 'ignore')`.

Comment: But if `line` is already ` str` in py3, is it allowed to be non-utf8?

Answer (score 8):

Example to handle no utf-8 characters

```
import string

test=u"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nHi <<First Name>>\nthis is filler text \xa325 more filler.\nadditilnal filler.\n\nyet more\xa0still more\xa0filler.\n\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\nmore\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nfiller.\x03\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    almost there \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nthe end\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

print ''.join(x for x in test if x in string.printable)
```

Comment: this removes all non-ascii characters, which includes many, many valid UTF-8 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fname, "r") as fp:
for line in fp:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This will be horribly wrong if the original input encoding is not in fact code page 1252. You remove the error, but produce garbage. The error is there for a reason, to prevent you from producing garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I would just encode in ascii.

```
line = line.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```