# BeautifulSoup parser and cirillic characters

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

guys!

I'm trying to parse this URL http://mapia.ua/ru/search?&city=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2&page=1&what=%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BE using BeautifulSoup.

But I have got a strange characters like this ��� �1 ��� "����"

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

URL = urllib.request.urlopen('http://mapia.ua/ru/search?city=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2&what=%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BE&page=1').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, 'html.parser')

print(soup.h3.get_text())
```

Can anybody help me?

P.S. I'm using python 3

Comment: The issue is the with the shell you are using to output the data, I get `ЖЭК №1 ООО "Дуэт"`  as my default encoding is utf-8, your accepted answer actually causes it to not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this :

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
   html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').encode("utf-8"))
```

From:

[How to correctly parse UTF-8 encoded HTML to Unicode strings with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205455/how-to-correctly-parse-utf-8-encoded-html-to-unicode-strings-with-beautifulsoup)

Also:

[Delete every non utf-8 symbols froms string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541968/delete-every-non-utf-8-symbols-froms-string)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Sorry! It doesn't help :(

Comment: Sorry forget the .encode("utf-8") at the end, this will remove all non utf8 char. If you want less specific char you will have to do it by regex.