# python: remove stray bytes from string

Tags: python

I have a string that I scraped online that looks like this:

> "trackingId":"f<0x85>©9\u0004+L<0x9b><0x91>\u001A<0x87>&\u0013i+T"},{"pendingInvitation":false

How do I remove the stray bytes `<0x85>`, `<0x9b>`, `<0x91>`, and `<0x87>` from my string?

Comment: You could use a "black list" for all unwanted bytes (`unwanted = (b'<0x85>', ...)`) and a generator expression for filtering: `"".join(b for bs in bytestring if b not in unwanted)`

Comment: Is that literally the string `'<0x85>'`? If I look at the source of your question I see lots of funny characters. Please include the actual string as code (e.g. the output of `repr(your_string)`), not as quoted text. Also, that looks pretty unlikely to be a tracking ID string unless it's binary and you messed up the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re

s = '"trackingId":"f<0x85>©9\u0004+L<0x9b><0x91>\u001A<0x87>&\u0013i+T"},{"pendingInvitation":false'
print(s)
print(re.sub(r'<0x\w{2}>', '',s))
```

with output:

```
"trackingId":"f<0x85>©9+L<0x9b><0x91><0x87>&i+T"},{"pendingInvitation":false
"trackingId":"f©9+L&i+T"},{"pendingInvitation":false
```

I have searched for the patten `<0x__>`, where the `__` is any char or digit of length 2.

Comment: Yes, but the byte is not actually a string

Comment: I thought you have `<0x9b>` and the such inside your actual string. You could filter out bytes that do not fit the encoding. such as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541968/delete-every-non-utf-8-symbols-from-string , but if that is not it i am not sure i understand your problem.