# How to remove strange whitespaces - php

Tags: php

I have some white spaces in my database displaying like the attached image.
i believe they are not being recognized as white spaces because i have used the following to remove them but they all failed.

```
1. preg_replace( '/^((?=^)(\s*))|((\s*)(?>$))/si', '',$data['home']);
2. trim($data['home']);
3. str_replace

(' ','',$data['home']);
```

How do i remove them please?

[how do i remove those black things that have question marks in them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dEL.png)

Comment: Check the character set of the data you want to remove. Once identified, you can replace it. Can you paste a sample of the character in your question.

Comment: Those are not white spaces. They are bytes or sequences or bytes that are not valid characters or characters that do not have a representation in the font. The font rendering engine uses a special character instead.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki i attached a picture of the character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the non UTF-8 characters from a string with the following code

```
line=line.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8")
```

Source: [Delete every non utf-8 symbols from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541968/delete-every-non-utf-8-symbols-from-string)

Here you can see line variable is first decoded and then encoded. This will remove your strange looking characters from your string.